# Búsquedas avanzadas en una lista con varias Keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tengo una lista de información que depende de 3 claves principales:

- EmpresaID
- RatioID
- PeriodoID

Me han pedido que cree botones para poder moverte libremente por la lista (dos a derecha e izquierda para cada una de las claves). Hasta el momento he conseguido que se pueda avanzar entre ellos (con botones de anterior y siguiente) y he creado otros botones que te llevan al primer elemento de la respectiva lista de cada clave y al último.

Mi problema es que, puesto que el link resultante es una combinación de las tres claves, si la Empresa X no tiene información del Periodo Y, aunque ambas existan por separado (y aunque haya otra Empresa Y que sí la tenga en ese Periodo) el resultado es, obviamente, un HttpNotFound.

El código que tengo en el controlador es el siguiente:

```
    public ActionResult Details(string EmpresaBMID, string PeriodoID, string RatioID)
    {
        if (EmpresaBMID == null || PeriodoID == null || RatioID == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        ResultadoRatioBM resultadoRatioBM = db.ResultadoRatioBM.Find(EmpresaBMID, PeriodoID, RatioID);
        List<ResultadoRatioBM> listaResultadoRatiosBM = db.ResultadoRatioBM.ToList();
        var indexRatio = listaResultadoRatiosBM.OrderBy(m => m.RatioID).ToList().IndexOf(resultadoRatioBM);
        var indexEmpresa = listaResultadoRatiosBM.OrderBy(m => m.EmpresaBM.Nombre).ToList().IndexOf(resultadoRatioBM);
        var indexPeriodo = listaResultadoRatiosBM.OrderBy(m => m.PeriodoID).ToList().IndexOf(resultadoRatioBM);

        // Ratios
        ViewBag.RatioFirst = listaResultadoRatiosBM.First().RatioID;
        ViewBag.RatioLast = listaResultadoRatiosBM.Last().RatioID;

        if (indexRatio > 0)
        {
            ViewBag.RatioAnt = listaResultadoRatiosBM.ElementAt(indexRatio - 1).RatioID;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.RatioAnt = listaResultadoRatiosBM.Last().RatioID;
        }
        if (indexRatio < listaResultadoRatiosBM.Count - 1)
        {
            ViewBag.RatioPost = listaResultadoRatiosBM.ElementAt(indexRatio + 1).RatioID;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.RatioPost = listaResultadoRatiosBM.First().RatioID;
        }

        // Empresa
        ViewBag.EmpresaBMFirst = listaResultadoRatiosBM.First().EmpresaBMID;
        ViewBag.EmpresaBMLast = listaResultadoRatiosBM.Last().EmpresaBMID;

        if (indexEmpresa > 0)
        {
            ViewBag.EmpresaBMAnt = listaResultadoRatiosBM.ElementAt(indexEmpresa - 1).EmpresaBMID;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.EmpresaBMAnt = listaResultadoRatiosBM.Last().EmpresaBMID;
        }
        if (indexEmpresa < listaResultadoRatiosBM.Count - 1)
        {
            ViewBag.EmpresaBMPost = listaResultadoRatiosBM.ElementAt(indexEmpresa + 1).EmpresaBMID;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.EmpresaBMPost = listaResultadoRatiosBM.First().EmpresaBMID;
        }

        // Periodo
        ViewBag.PeriodoFirst = listaResultadoRatiosBM.First().PeriodoID;
        ViewBag.PeriodoLast = listaResultadoRatiosBM.Last().PeriodoID;

        if (indexPeriodo > 0)
        {
            ViewBag.PeriodoAnt = listaResultadoRatiosBM.ElementAt(indexPeriodo - 1).PeriodoID;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.PeriodoAnt = listaResultadoRatiosBM.Last().PeriodoID;
        }
        if (indexPeriodo < listaResultadoRatiosBM.Count - 1)
        {
            ViewBag.PeriodoPost = listaResultadoRatiosBM.ElementAt(indexPeriodo + 1).PeriodoID;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.PeriodoPost = listaResultadoRatiosBM.First().PeriodoID;
        }
        if (resultadoRatioBM == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(resultadoRatioBM);
    }
```

Y estos son los botones creados en el CSHTML:

```
    <h4>ResultadoRatioBM</h4>
<div class="botones pull-right">
    @Html.ActionLink("<<", "Details", new { EmpresaBMID = Model.EmpresaBMID, PeriodoID = Model.PeriodoID, RatioID = ViewBag.RatioFirst }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
    @Html.ActionLink("<", "Details", new { EmpresaBMID = Model.EmpresaBMID, PeriodoID = Model.PeriodoID, RatioID = ViewBag.RatioAnt }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
    <strong>Ratio ID</strong>
    @Html.ActionLink(">", "Details", new { EmpresaBMID = Model.EmpresaBMID, PeriodoID = Model.PeriodoID, RatioID = ViewBag.RatioPost }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
    @Html.ActionLink(">>", "Details", new { EmpresaBMID = Model.EmpresaBMID, PeriodoID = Model.PeriodoID, RatioID = ViewBag.RatioLast }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="botones2 pull-right">
    @Html.ActionLink("<<", "Details", new { EmpresaBMID = ViewBag.EmpresaBMFirst, PeriodoID = Model.PeriodoID, RatioID = Model.RatioID }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
    @Html.ActionLink("<", "Details", new { EmpresaBMID = ViewBag.EmpresaBMAnt, PeriodoID = Model.PeriodoID, RatioID = Model.RatioID }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
    <strong>Empresa</strong>
    @Html.ActionLink(">", "Details", new { EmpresaBMID = ViewBag.EmpresaBMPost, PeriodoID = Model.PeriodoID, RatioID = Model.RatioID }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
    @Html.ActionLink(">>", "Details", new { EmpresaBMID = ViewBag.EmpresaBMLast, PeriodoID = Model.PeriodoID, RatioID = Model.RatioID }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="botones3 pull-right">
    @Html.ActionLink("<<", "Details", new { EmpresaBMID = Model.EmpresaBMID, PeriodoID = ViewBag.PeriodoFirst, RatioID = Model.RatioID }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
    @Html.ActionLink("<", "Details", new { EmpresaBMID = Model.EmpresaBMID, PeriodoID = ViewBag.PeriodoAnt, RatioID = Model.RatioID }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
    <strong>Periodo ID</strong>
    @Html.ActionLink(">", "Details", new { EmpresaBMID = Model.EmpresaBMID, PeriodoID = ViewBag.PeriodoPost, RatioID = Model.RatioID }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
    @Html.ActionLink(">>", "Details", new { EmpresaBMID = Model.EmpresaBMID, PeriodoID = ViewBag.PeriodoLast, RatioID = Model.RatioID }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
</div>
<br />
```

Mi pregunta es:

¿Habría alguna manera de controlar que nunca se llegue a esa situación?

Como, por ejemplo, desactivando el botón cuando no exista X Periodo o X Ratio en X Empresa, quizá por JavaScript o, si es posible, en C#.

Gracias de antemano.